Empty Columns in Confusion matrix
I am training on pre-processed APTOS 2019 dataset for disease grading and the last two columns of my confusion matrix are constantly zero every time. Data is distributed as:

class 0: 1805 images
class 1: 370 images
class 3: 999 images
class 4: 193 images
class 5: 295 images

Here are results on 70 epochs:
Test acc=77%

Confusion matrix:
[[258   3   1   0   0]
 [  6  38  16   0   0]
 [ 13  13 130   0   0]
 [  0   7  22   0   0]
 [  4   9  30   0   0]]

Class-wise accuracy on test set of model:
[98.47328244 63.33333333 83.33333333 0. 0.]

Sensitivity (Recall) for each class:
[0.98473282 0.63333333 0.83333333 0. 0.]

Specificity for each class:
[0.98513011 0.95416667 0.92592593 0.94727273 0.92181818]

I tried applying class weights, stratified k-fold cross validation but it didn’t help.

Showing the code you used to train the model might allow folks to be able identify your problem.  Check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

How can I improve training accuracy for this, my training accuracy is not exceeding from 76% , I am using a custom model where model is only working good for class 0 and class 2 (which has maximum number of samples).
